# Continuous color scale from discrete domain of strings?

Tags: javascript, d3.js, heatmap

I'm implementing a heatmap in which the cell background color is determined by a d3 color scale. Some of the values are categorical; their value can be of N different arbitrary string-type categories like ["6TH", "7TH", "5TH", "4TH"].

Given a start color d3.rgb("blue") and an end color d3.rgb("red"), how can I construct color scale that maps a discrete domain of strings into a continuous color range?

I tried

```
var scale = d3.scale.ordinal()
    .domain(["6TH", "7TH", "5TH", "4TH"])
    .rangeBands( [ d3.rgb("blue"), d3.rgb("red") ] );
```

which obviously doesn't work.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

First, I would consider using one of the readily-available Colorbrewer scales; see [colorbrewer2.org](http://colorbrewer2.org). These are also available as JavaScript and CSS files in D3's git repository; see [lib/colorbrewer](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/tree/master/lib/colorbrewer). For example, if you have four discrete values in your domain, and you want a red-blue diverging scale, you could say:

```
var color = d3.scale.ordinal()
    .domain(["6TH", "7TH", "5TH", "4TH"])
    .range(colorbrewer.RdBu[4]);
```

(You'll need a `<script src="colorbrewer.js"></script>` somewhere before this, too.) Colorbrewer has a variety of well-designed sequential, diverging and categorical color scales.

If you insist on rolling your own color scale, I strongly recommend interpolating in [L*a*b* or HCL color space](http://bl.ocks.org/3014589) for accurate perception. You can do this using [d3.interpolateLab](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Transitions#wiki-d3_interpolateLab) or [d3.interpolateHcl](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Transitions#wiki-d3_interpolateHcl). For example, `d3.interpolateLab("red", "blue")(.5)` returns a color halfway between red and blue.

To compute the colors for your ordinal scale's range, you can use an interpolator, or you might find a temporary linear scale more convenient. For example:

```
var categories = ["6TH", "7TH", "5TH", "4TH"];

var color = d3.scale.ordinal()
    .domain(categories)
    .range(d3.range(categories.length).map(d3.scale.linear()
      .domain([0, categories.length - 1])
      .range(["red", "blue"])
      .interpolate(d3.interpolateLab)));
```

Comment: Update: D3's Colorbrewer lib has moved to the [d3-scale-chromatic](https://github.com/d3/d3-scale-chromatic) repository.

Answer (score 3):

You have the right idea, you just need to process each R/G/B color channel. For example, in vanilla JavaScript you can do the following:

```
var a = [255, 0, 0], // First color
    b = [0, 0, 255], // Other color
    bands = 5,       // Bands is the length of your domain
    i, 
    delta = [];      // Difference between color in each channel

// Compute difference between each color
for (i = 0; i < 4; i++){
  delta[i] = (a[i] - b[i]) / (bands + 1);
}

// Use that difference to create your bands
for (i = 0; i <= bands + 1; i++){
  var r = Math.round(a[0] - delta[0] * i);
  var g = Math.round(a[1] - delta[1] * i);
  var b = Math.round(a[2] - delta[2] * i);
  console.log("<div style='background-color: #" + dec2hex(r) + dec2hex(g) + dec2hex(b) + "'>Band " + i + "</div>");
}

// A helper function for formatting
function dec2hex(i) {
  return (i+0x100).toString(16).substr(-2).toUpperCase();
}
```

According to the [d3 documentation](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Colors), you can extract each color channel using the `r`, `g` and `b` attributes of a color object:

> `# d3.rgb(color)`
>
> Constructs a new RGB color by parsing the specified color string. If color is not a string, it is coerced to a string; thus, this constructor can also be used to create a copy of an existing color, or force the conversion of a d3.hsl color to RGB.
>
> ...
>
> The resulting color is stored as red, green and blue integer channel values in the range [0,255]. The channels are available as the r, g and b attributes of the returned object.

So at the top of the example above, you could say:

```
var myColor = d3.rgb("blue"),
    a = [myColor.r, myColor.g, myColor.b],
...
```

Does that help?

Answer (score 0):

You can always chain an ordinal scale and a linear scale.

The first scale will create quantifiable values from your discrete values, and the second scale will interpolate these values on a color scale.

Something like this:

```js
// Your categories
var data = ["6TH", "7TH", "5TH", "4TH"],

  // Define ordinal to linear scale...
  ordinal = d3.scale.ordinal().domain(data).rangePoints([0, 1]),

  // ...and linear to color scale
  linear = d3.scale.linear().domain([0, 1]).range([d3.rgb("blue"), d3.rgb("red")]);

// Now define your artificial 'compound' scale
function scale(d) {
  return linear(ordinal(d));
}

// And then use it on your D3 code
d3.selectAll('div')
  .data(data)
  .enter()
  .append('div')
  .style('background', scale) // <- et voilà ;)
  .text(function(d) {
    return d;
  });
```

```css
div {
  color: white;
  width: 3em;
  padding: 1em;
  margin: .2em
  text-align: center;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-weight: bold
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>
```